# How to update several MySQL DBs together?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

On the same server, I have around 30 sites, and the DB of 30 sites have the same structure, now I want to update a table: `tx_tip`(same table name on 30 DBs). instead of using phpmyadmin to update one by one, is there a way that I can use mysql command to update all the DBs together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update multiple tables using a JOIN. If the tables are in different databases, you have to put the database prefix in the query.

```
UPDATE db1.tx_tip t1
JOIN db2.tx_tip t2
JOIN db3.tx_tip t3
...
SET t1.col = new_val,
    t2.col = new_val,
    t3.col = new_val,
WHERE <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain this table on a regular basis you may consider to create a simple stored procedure that might look something like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_tx_tip(IN p_id INT, IN p_new_value VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE db_name VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tx_tip';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  SET @id = p_id, @new_value = p_new_value;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO db_name;
    IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', db_name, '.tx_tip t SET t.value = ? WHERE t.id = ?');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @new_value, @id;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it like

```
CALL sp_update_tx_tip(1, 'new value');
```

It will pull names of all databases that have `tx_tip` table from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, construct and execute update statements for you.